# How to force windows 10 to refresh network location

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, samba

I have a raspberry pi with Samba share and attached piDrive. I currently backup from windows to that networked drive (old address 192.168.1.117).

I've forced the pi to use eth0 only and assigned a static IP address.

After a samba restart and PC restart, the pi3 shows as a network device (\RASPBERRYPI3) however on clicking I get 'not found' and an 0x80070035 error.

If I manually add the new IP address to a mapped drive, it works fine (192.168.1.199) and I've successfully added it as a new drive. The issue is windows won't allow me to backup using the built in backup feature as it will only allow a network browseable location (the other computers on the network \raspberrypi3). Is there anyway I can force this to rescan for the new IP address or reset it in some way to allow access?

Many thanks,

Luke

Comment: I've made sure the location services in services.msc are set to auto and restarted both. I've also restarted any network location services running and still no luck.

Answer (score -1):

The ONLY way I could do this after 6 hours of tinkering was to change the raspberry pi hostname. This was much easier than anything else, despite having to resolve a few issues on the pi side. I did try changing it initially (windows found and accessed no trouble) then changing it back, but again windows couldnt find it? Eventually I just opted for sticking with the changed name and resolved the Pi-side issues. Not ideal but it was the only thing that would work for me.